# admin menus Joomla 3.3.1 disappeared

Tags: joomla, admin, menubar, joomla3.3

All admin menus in Joomla 3.3.1 suddenly disappeared!
I worked at the site's user groups and adjusted a little CSS using firebug, when I suddenly lost all admin menubar, buttons / content in the subheader and content in the header
None change in the core files and no errors are shown

You can see the image....[image: The backend without any menuitems]

Comment: All users except one super user was deleted in the database.
After this succeeded by copy / paste html from another site to create a new Super User. And even though ALL permissions definitely were the same, all functions are back again.
Naturally, I have deleted the Super User, which did not work

Answer (score 3):

This is not a programming issue. It's hard to know which exact change created the problem but if you are playing with user groups most likely you accidently put yourself into a group which does not have permission to see the menu module . Go to the module manager (add `index.php?option=com_modules` to the admin url.) and change the settings on the admin menu module to public ... then check to make sure that your user group has permission to see "special."

Comment: I wish you were right. It was the first thing I checked - both on the site and in the database.
When I use firebug to copy / paste html with menus / links from another site, I can save changes. :-(

Comment: I have no idea what you mean about copying and pasting links .. all that has happened is that the menu is hidden of course the links still work. What you want to do is to unhide the menu. Did you check the access level of the menu module against the groups you are a member of?

Comment: My most important lesson learnt here: Don't MESS with Special access level.

Comment: Also, once setting access back in the database, you have to log out and back in again for changes to become visible.